# How can I get the dimensions of a three.js group?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can get the dimensions of a [mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh) (Three.Mesh):

```
mymesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
var bbox = mymesh.geometry.boundingBox;
var bboxWidth = bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x;
var bboxHeight = bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y;
var bboxDepth = bbox.max.z - bbox.min.z;
```

But a [group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) that has multiple meshes within it:

```
var mygroup = new THREE.Group();
```

doesn't have a computeBoundingBox()/boundingBox?

Comment: You could do it by recursively iterating over all children and finding the min and max of all bounding boxes

Comment: @AndyRay but they might be in different positions within the group. hmm maybe I could get the min/max of each. and then the smallest min and the biggest max of all the meshes would be the dimensions or something. but I was hoping maybe there's a helper function inside three.js that does this for me.

Comment: @foreyez Try `box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mygroup );`

Comment: @WestLangley nice thanks, but when I do groupWidth = box.max.x - box.min.x; I get slightly different value than mine below, it's 2 points bigger for some reason. But maybe I'm overlooking something. regardless, if you add this as the answer below your method is probably the better way.

Comment: @foreyez The three.js solution is not necessarily the _minimum_ bounding box. I find this unfortunate, but it was done this way for performance reasons. Feel free to update your own answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to one of the commentors, it was an easy solution:

```js
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(theGroup);
const size = new Vector3();
bbox.getSize(size);

var sizeX = size.x;
var sizeY = size.y;
var sizeZ = size.z;
```

> Note that for a tilted planeGeometry, the size will not the size actual length/width of the edges.